# VB6/Access SQL SELECT NOT IN

Tags: sql, select, vb6

I've narrowed my code down and the issue I'm facing is when trying to adapt some code to include more results.

Data tables for reference:

```
**OG_InUse**
*C_ID*
E011
E011_A
F012_D


**Csrc**
*C_ID*
E011
F012
G001
```

So the code that works but doesn't return results in cases where there's an "_*"

```
sSql = "SELECT DISTINCT C_ID FROM Csrc WHERE C_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT C_ID FROM OG_InUse)"
```

Result:
F012
G001

The issue arises when I'm trying to expand the above query to return just the first 4 characters of C_ID from OG_InUse (to remove cases where there's an _A or _D, etc.):

```
sSql = "SELECT DISTINCT C_ID FROM Csrc WHERE C_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Left(C_ID, 4) AS C_OG_ID FROM OG_InUse)"
```

which I'd like to result in the following (but access just continues attempting to process): 
G001

Any suggestions what may be causing the query to trip up like that? My first thought is checking into the alias but I'm not certain how I could start testing this beyond breaking it up (which I've done and my subquery returns the correct set of results).

Comment: How many records are in the two tables ?

Comment: This is for a large and evergrowing database that is about 1000 records in the 'Csrc' table and another 250,000+ in the 'OG_InUse' table. And yeah, like you mentioned, the correlated subquery does work... just painfully slow for each screen of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your further information about the size of the tables:

1. Access will run out of steam before long
2. If you could separate the suffix of OG_InUse.C_ID into a separate field, your query could be better optimised (but I don't know whether that justifies the effort...)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up grahamj42. I'll consider another remedy by possibly continuing to use the original code of WHERE NOT IN but instead upon the creation of the OG_InUse records I may insert a dummy 4character record associated with each _1,_2,_3,_4 which would remove that scenario... Not the prettiest solution but it'd be effective.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to find a SQL solution using `EXISTS` instead of `IN`.
The query you need should use the `LIKE` keyword.
For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C_ID
FROM  CSrc
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OG_InUse
    WHERE OG_InUse.C_ID LIKE (CSrc.C_ID + '*')
)
```

**EDIT**

1. for this to preform you'll need to ensure that C_ID on OG_InUse is indexed.
2. for ordered results, you can restore your original `DISTINCT` keyword, it kinda sorts your results (I've amended my answer to show  this)

**FURTHER EDIT**

`EXISTS` is generally preferred over `IN` because `EXISTS` subqueries often do not needed to be evaluated in full to obtain the same result, thereby reducing CPU and execution time. In this case, the `SELECT *` subquery only has to be evaluated to find the first matching OG_InUse, i.e. the `SELECT *` doesn't get evaluated in full.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! I tried what you suggested but it's taking a great deal of time to process the query (and it won't return ordered by default anymore because of the comparison). Is there any particular reason why that'd be happening you can think of? I've done a bit of reading on why to use EXIST instead of IN and will certainly make that a regular practice. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I didn't know one could do correlated subqueries in Access, but they're usually a slow way to achieve the result.